# Convert string (was a function) back to function in Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have this function below as a string.  How would I convert it back into a function?  I am pulling event handlers from JQuery events and I want to store them as string then convert them back because they will be saved in mySQL

```
function () {

    if (!GActiveClick) {
        return;
    }
    SaveProduct();
}
```

Comment: why would you do this? eval()

Comment: You can use `eval()` to execute Javascript in a string, but this is normally considered a Very Bad Practice. It isn't making sense to me why you would want to store JQuery event functions in a MySql table. Maybe you should rethink what you are trying to do.

Comment: @js1568. It doesn't have to be `eval`.

Comment: My Plan was to capture the state of a page then save this information then restore it at a later date.

Comment: @Robert. Then, it's a bad way of doing it...

Comment: Pulling all the JQuery events along with the HTML then re assigning these functions seemed a lot easier then actually going back an hard coding all the JQuery handlers.

Comment: @gdoron what would you suggest then?

Comment: @gdoron sorry for not understanding what do you mean store the "data"?  Just store the HtML?  I feel like it would be a pain to manually hardcode the JQuery functions to be reinitialized...

Answer (score 22, accepted):

```
var func = new Function(theFunctionString);
func();
```

[**MDN**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function):

> new Function ([arg1[, arg2[, ... argN]],] functionBody)
>
> ***Parameters***
>
> **arg1, arg2, ... argN**
>   Names to be used by the function as formal argument names. Each must be a string that corresponds to a valid JavaScript identifier or a list of such strings separated with a comma; for example "x", "theValue", or "a,b".
>
> **functionBody**
>   A string containing the JavaScript statements comprising the function definition.

---

**Update:**

All this a **very** bad practice!
You should have a generic function that get parameters that build what you want. The only thing that change are the parameters. Store those parameters in the DB you have.

Comment: thanks for the answer.  I was just looking for a quick way of saving this information but if its such bad practice I will make sure to do it this way.

Comment: My answer does not require to store parameters in any DB

Answer (score 4):

Use the `return` when using `new Function()` and execute it, like this

```
new Function('return ' + fn_string)();
```

Example:

```js
function hackerAll(a, b) {
  var result = a*b
  return result
}

class Doggy{
  method1(){
    return 123123*342343
  }
}

var fn_string = hackerAll.toString()
var back_to_fn = new Function(`return ${fn_string}`)() //This restore the function with name, params and all, even es7 class works

var class_string = Doggy.toString()
var back_to_class = new Function(`return ${class_string}`)()

console.log('fn as it', hackerAll)
console.log('fn string', fn_string)
console.log('restored fn', back_to_fn)
console.log('restored class', back_to_class)
```

Answer (score 1):

Javascript provides the new- keyword for functions

```
var foo = new Function("arg", ... , "<implementation string>");
```

see here for example...
http://www.permadi.com/tutorial/jsFunc/