# function argument as string but execute as function?

Tags: javascript, arrays, string, function, arguments

I have a function (named “chal") which simply console.log() the arguments if they are NOT a function or call the function otherwise.

```
function chal(){
    for(var i = 0, iLen = arguments.length; i<iLen;i++)
        if(typeof arguments[i] == "function")
            //if argument is a function, call it
            arguments[i]();
        else
            //if argument is NOT a function, console.log the value
            console.log(arguments[i]);
}
```

I have an array (named “arr") which contain a function “AS A STRING”

```
var arr = [
    "argumentAsString",
    123,
    "function(){console.log('this is a function');}"
];
```

I need “chal" function to run with arguments from “arr” array but the function as string in the array get called as a function.

I know it's very confusing... here is jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/YqBLm/1/

I know it's wield but I actually ran into a situation when I need to do such thing... I basically passed the function from server-side to client as string (function.toString()) and now i need to pass it as an argument to a function on client-side... Can anyone think of anything?

Thanks a lot in advance!!

Comment: You need [eval()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/eval) in your case, but why you store functions as strings in array?

Comment: @Givi: I don't think u can store function as function in array in JS...

Comment: You can! `var arr = ["argumentAsString", 123, function(){console.log('this is a function');}]; arr[2]();` since, functions is just object you can store reference of that function in variables or in arrays or in another objects.

Comment: [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/GKDev/33j9f/)

Comment: ok, i'm sorry... my eyes played trick on me... I actually thought of it before and for some reason i insist that it doesn't work...

Comment: @Givi I think we might be misinterpreting the question - I think he means that he's receiving the function from the server as a string, so if I'm right, that string would have to be parsed into a function. OP is that correct?

Comment: Givi is right, I can just new Function(s) and store it in an array! Credit for Givi!! Thanks man!

Comment: possible duplicate of [Convert string (was a function) back to function in Javascript](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10901217/convert-string-was-a-function-back-to-function-in-javascript)

Answer (score 2):

If you encapsulate the function in a module (object), you could call it like so:

**JavaScript**

```
var module = {
    argumentAsString: function(){..}
}

var arr = [
    "argumentAsString",
    123,
    "function(){console.log('this is a function');}"
];

function chal(){
    for(var i = 0, iLen = arguments.length; i<iLen;i++)
        if(module.hasOwnProperty[arguments[i]])
            //if argument is a function, call it
            module[arguments[i]]();
        else
            //if argument is NOT a function, console.log the value
            console.log(arguments[i]);
}
```

**EDIT**

I may have misinterpreted the question! :p

Try assigning that function to a variable, and storing that variable in the array instead:

```
var fcn= function(){
    console.log('this is a function');
}

var arr = [
    "argumentAsString",
    123,
    fcn
];
```

**EDIT 2**

If I'm right, neither of the above two answers will solve your problem. See this similar question: [Convert string (was a function) back to function in Javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10901217/convert-string-was-a-function-back-to-function-in-javascript)

Comment: You cannot use `function` as a variable identifier. Otherwise, yes.